# Wpf forms and Office 2003 excel addin

Tags: excel, wpf-controls, ms-office, excel-2003

I would like to create a wpf control form that can be shown on clicking a menuitem. but this application should be an addin to excel. can someone help me here?

Comment: Maybe you should add what you tried and google a little if you haven't tried anything. This could help you on your way: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc668205.aspx

Comment: @ToonCasteele The question is tagged with `excel-2003` though, might not be so easy!

Comment: There are templates available for office 2003 too. Just google "create add-in office 2003" or something.

Comment: WPF templates though?

Answer (score 0):

Not WPF,but Excel 2003 can be used to create dialogs. See the SDK or http://xll.codeplex.com and the dialog.h header file. The file error.cpp has an example of how to use it. Pretty old school, but it works.